# How to get ViewPager working with dates?

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

Basically I'm trying to create finite sliding tabs (say, 2 weeks). The middle tab is the current date, You can't scroll into future dates, but can go back as far as the tabs will take you. This should be based on a calendar (legit dates, etc.) and look like a timeline. A good example is [the Fitocracy app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitocracy.app&hl=en), which I'm trying to imitate.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [Infinite ViewPager](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager) lib (sample below) and [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) lib for smooth tabs names.

```
//XML
<com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
// Code
PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(yourFragmentPagerAdapter);
viewPager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);
```

I think that using 2 libs above is enough to achieve what you want.